# Load <div> in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing problem in loading div into my javascript,
My code is:-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#example').hide();

    $("#myDiv").tooltip({trigger:'hover',placement:'left',html:true,title:'Rate Us'}).popover({trigger:'click',placement:'top',content:$("#example").html(),});
});

<div id="example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon   glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
</div>
```

I  am not able to load button in the example div on popover.

What should I write in `content:$("#example").html(),` to load example div?

Please help me.

Comment: still not loading! It is displaying all my code, and no button.

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue in order to get some help, maybe...

Comment: what type of tooltip are you using? if bootstrap means use popover , tooltip doesnt hav content option

Comment: in tooltip content I want to load another div. How can I do this?

Comment: surely that popover will be throwing an error - it will be expecting something after your last comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use `content:` for html content on popovers without setting `html:true`

see here for more information about popovers http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CsR5Z/1/